# How to enter text into attribute tables with QGIS graphical model?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

I am using QGIS 2.14 to open NC files for chlorophyll satellite data with the end goal of compiling chlorophyll values for many dates (each its own initial file) in a spreadsheet. I know how to do the work manually, but I want to automate the process in the model due to the bulk of files I am working with.

Currently, my process is to manually open each file in QGIS, then I have been using the model. I run zonal statistics for each file based on the study area, then I add a date attribute in each file. My problem is that I can't figure out how to fill in the date values (using the format 2000_01, 2000_02, etc) using field calculator or advanced python field calculator. I need the date attributes in order to merge the files for export.

I think this would be possible in ArcMap, so can I do it in QGIS with minimal/no python?

I've included the model that I've started with.[image]

Comment: How do you know what date to use for the current layer? Is it a property of the layer, or do you want to manually enter it when you run the model?

Comment: The data is available online for specific dates, so I select the dates then and name the files based on the date selected. Each initial file can only correspond to one date.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new string input, called date. Set the default value to YYYY_MM - this will indicate to the user of the model what format they should use to input the date.

[image]

Use the `Field Calculator` algorithm *instead* of the `Add field to attribute table` algorithm. For the formula, use either `@date` or `parameter('date')`.

[image]